# C++ wrong usage of close and dup2?

Tags: c++, linux, file, unix

I wrote the following code:

```
void execute() {
    std::cout << "smash pid is " << getpid() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int pid=fork();
    if (pid==0)
    {
        int fd=open("my_file.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0666); // 3=my_file
        dup2(fd,1); // replace output stream
        close(fd); //close duplicate access to my_file
        execute();
        close (1); // close last access to my file
    }
    else if (pid>0)
    {
        std::cout << "Hello!" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

my question is am I doing things correctly? and can the main process still have access to print to terminal as usual?

I tried to add notes of what I am doing, please let me know if something isn't clear.

---

Version 2:

```
int main()
{
    int pid=fork();
    if (pid==0)
    {
        close (1);
        int fd=open("my_file.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0666); // 3=my_file
        execute();
        close (1); // close last access to my file
    }
    else if (pid>0)
    {
        std::cout << "Hello!" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're trying to redirect stdout to your text file in the child process, correct?  Version 1 looks OK.  Q: Does version 1 work as you intended?  Q: Does version 2 fail? Q: Why are you doing this in the first place?  What are you trying to demonstrate here?

Answer (score 0):

> my question is am I doing things correctly?

Your child will have its output directed into the opened file and the parent will write "Hello!" to the `stdout` that was provided to the program at startup. It looks like that's what you want, so, yes.

I'd use `pid_t` instead of `int` for the process id though, but that may be different on different platforms.

> can the main process still have access to print to terminal as usual?

Yes. The `dup2` in the child process does not affect the parent process in any way.

One note. Use `fileno(stdout)` instead of `1`:

```
dup2(fd, fileno(stdout));
// and
close(fileno(stdout)); // not needed really
```

The `int fileno(FILE*)` function returns the internal file descriptor from the standard `FILE*` that is `stdout`. It's just a way of making it clearer to readers of the code.

---

You could however redirect `stdout` to a file using the standard C++ function [`std::freopen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/freopen) instead.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#include <cstdio>    // std::freopen
#include <iostream>

void execute() {
    std::cout << "smash pid is " << getpid() << std::endl;
    system("echo the redirect is inherited by the grand children too");
}

int main() {
    pid_t pid = fork();

    if(pid < 0) {                   // check for errors
        std::perror("fork failed");
        return 1;
    }

    if(pid == 0) {                  // child
        // using std::freopen
        if(std::freopen("my_file.txt", "w", stdout) == nullptr) {
            std::perror("freopen failed");
            return 1;
        }

        execute();

        return 0;
    }

    // parent
    std::cout << "Parent says hello!\n";

    // wait for child
    int wstatus;
    if(waitpid(pid, &wstatus, 0) == pid) {
        std::cout << "child exited with status " << wstatus << '\n';
    } else {
        std::perror("waitpid failed");
    }
}
```

Comment: got you, can you suggest any edits to version 1 or nothing can be done?

Comment: @daniel Sure - I'd encapsulate the naked file descriptor in a RAII class that supports these operation on a higher level - but again, that's a completely new and different question. That type of question is more suited for [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) - Two things though. You should always check for errors (both `open` and `dup2` may fail) and you could add `wait` or `waitpid` in the parent process to wait for the child to finish.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: He already *has* a file encapsulation that supports these operations.  Namely the `rdbuf()` operation on `std::cout`.

Comment: @BenVoigt True to a certain degree I guess. I've never figured out how to truly redirect an ostream. When using `fork()` one very often `exec` afterwards and then swapping `rdbuf`s doesn't help. In OP:s simplified code, it'd work fine though, agree.